# Retrieving graph info web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I need some help for my query.
On this page https://ski-resort-stats.com/Hemsedal/, section SNOW HISTORY FOR HEMSEDAL I am trying to retrieving the infos on the graph (snow fall for each year). I am trying to start with one year (2013-2014).

I think I found the part associated in the html code:
[Screenshot from the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUX7Z.png)

For that:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                         
import requests

url="https://ski-resort-stats.com/Hemsedal/"                                              
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")                             
gdp_table = soup.find("g", attrs={"class": "highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker"})                                                                       
gdp_table_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("path")`
```

But I am guetting this error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'". Tried with other elements from the html codes but without success. Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: The graph and its data are generated dynamically by javascript, so it isn't visible for `requests`.

Comment: @joni So it there a way to retrieve those information or none ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is embedded within the page in JavaScript form. You can use this example how to parse it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://ski-resort-stats.com/Hemsedal/"
html_doc = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"wpDataCharts\[.*?\] = ({.*})", html_doc).group(1)
data = re.sub(r"([a-z_]+):", r'"\1":', data)
data = re.sub(r'"http":', "http:", data)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for series in data["render_data"]["options"]["series"]:
    print(series["name"], series["data"])

print()
print("week =", data["render_data"]["options"]["xAxis"]["categories"])
```

Prints:

```
2013-2014 [0, 0, 0, 25, 28, 36, 36.5, 53.5, 77.5, 89.5, 125.5, 151.5, 159.5, 163.5, 177.5, 173.5, 175, 166, 171, 173.5, 169.5, 166, 158.5]
2014-2015 [0, 0, 0, 52, 70, 67, 74.5, 78, 74, 88, 98, 102, 109.5, 113, 113, 109.5, 110.5, 98, 95, 95, 99, 108, 102]
2015-2016 [0, 0, 0, 11.5, 25.5, 34, 37, 52, 64, 76, 82, 73, 79, 105, 118, 120, 136, 141, 116, 116, 100, 97, 95]
2016-2017 [0, 0, 0, 42, 33, 22, 17, 31, 25, 40, 47, 22, 15, 17, 15, 20, 47, 50, 63, 59, 57, 51, 50]
2017-2018 [10, 10, 40, 66, 64, 64, 48, 67, 77, 85, 120, 120, 140, 155, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 168, 170, 180, 180]
2012-2013 [0, 0, 0, 61.5, 60, 61, 76.5, 90.5, 95, 85, 85, 85, 87.5, 100, 102.5, 102.5, 100.5, 104, 101, 100, 99, 97.5, 95]
2018-2019 [0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 33, 48, 49, 50, 75, 68, 68, 115, 115, 115, 80, 80, 85, 85, 110, 110, 110, 110]
2019-2020 [45, 45, 40, 80, 80, 80, 97, 107, 107, 107, 107, 113, 113, 113, 113, 118, 118, 127, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0]
week = [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing thank you !! I'll try to work with that but seems perfect for what I need !

Comment: Hi @Andrej I am trying to use the code for other pages with the same format, but some of them are raising the error JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 2198 (char 2197), like this one https://ski-resort-stats.com/westendorf-skiwelt-wilder-kaiser-brixental/ . I tried to find help online but I don't really understand what is happening. Could you help me once more ?

Comment: @ClaireS To not clutter the comment section, I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: okay yes no problem. here is the new subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182620/web-scraping-doesnt-work-for-all-links-expecting-delimiter-line-1-column-2 thank you !

Answer (score 1):

As @joni pointed out, the site runs javascript after it is initially loaded to populate the page with the graph data. The code below uses [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to load the page, grab the data point elements on the graph for `2013-2014`, and then hovers over each of those points so the info tooltip with the actual data is made visible:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://ski-resort-stats.com/Hemsedal/')
results = []
for i in d.execute_script('''return document.querySelectorAll('g > path[fill="#7cb5ec"]')''')[:-1]:
    a = ActionChains(d)
    a.move_to_element(i).perform()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    results.append(d.execute_script('''
     function* get_hover_data(y_range){
         for (var i of document.querySelectorAll('text[x="8"][data-z-index="1"][y="18"]')){
             if (i.children.length === 5){
                 yield [i.children[0].textContent, i.children[3].textContent]
             }
         }

     }
     return [...get_hover_data('2013-2014')];
    '''))

_, *final_results = [i[0] for i in results if i]
```

Output:

```
[['45', '0'], ['46', '0'], ['47', '0'], ['48', '25'], ['49', '28'], ['50', '36'], ['51', '37'], ['52', '53,5'], ['1', '77,5'], ['2', '89,5'], ['3', '125,5'], ['4', '151,5'], ['5', '159,5'], ['6', '163,5'], ['7', '177,5'], ['8', '173,5'], ['9', '175'], ['10', '166'], ['11', '171'], ['12', '173,5'], ['13', '170'], ['14', '166'], ['15', '158,5']]
```

Comment: thank you @Ajax1234 for this lead ! That is way over what I had imagined ^^
On thing thow, when I run the code and print final_results I am only getting weeks 2 to 15 (1 to 15 for results), so missing the first weeks. Any ideas why ?